# how can we print the exact data format from PDF or image file to excel or word using selenium java

Tags: java

I need a help from you guys i have tried to extract the data from PDF  to excel but i am getting data in only one cell. please find my code below and let me know the solution.

```
public void readPDFfromintranet() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filein);
    PDDocument pdfdocument = PDDocument.load(fis);
    int count = pdfdocument.getNumberOfPages();
    System.out.println(count);
    PDFTextStripper textstriper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String doctext = textstriper.getText(pdfdocument);
    System.out.println(doctext);
    
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    sheet.createRow(0);
    sheet.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue(doctext);
    FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Raghavendra\\Isolve\\Output.xls");
    workbook.write(fileout);
    workbook.close();
    
    pdfdocument.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium.

Comment: Given the information provided in your question, your code does exactly what you describe. It extracts text from a PDF document, writes it into a single cell in your excel sheet and writes this to a file. If you need a more fine-grained reading of you PDF document you should maybe provide at least a screen shot of the PDF document and describe more precisely what you are intending to do.